# Using LibreOffice and having problems, copying details

Tags: windows-xp, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer

A staff member in our office is having trouble pasting details from a spreadsheet {In any format} to a template in .ott format.

When pasting and details from the spreadsheet, it removes some of the previous formatting already placed on the template. This includes removing of our office brand(logo), and mis-alining some of the "input text" area's which are supposed too be lined up horizontally.

I have attempted to change the spreadsheet into a LibreOffice format in the hopes that this may resolve the issue but to not avail, the problem still occurs.

Software being run is LibreOffice 4.0 on Windows XP OS.

I need to know if anyone has previously had this problem, and if so, how they resolved it.

Thank you in advance too any help that you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `Paste Special` and only pasting either `formula's` or the `text` (NOT the formats)? What is the result then?